# Jenkins Groovy StackOverFlowError when accessing a property

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to write a small job DSL, but I'm struggling with getting `java.lang.StackOverflowError` errors when accessing a class property.

Therefore not even a complex script is necessary. See the following script

```
class Komponente {

  String name

  Komponente(name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  String getName() {
    return this.name
  }  

  String toString() {
    return 'Klasse: Komponente (name: [' + this.name +'])'
  }
}

Komponente komponente = new Komponente('Testkomponente')

println 'Erstellte Komponente: ' + komponente.getName()
```

​

When running it on the [Groovy web console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) it works fine, but when running it in my Jenkins I get:

```
FATAL: null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:1038)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:406)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:425)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor316.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
  at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1850)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3758)
  at Komponente.getProperty(script)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:456)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:290)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:257)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedGetProperty$2.callStatic(Unknown Source)
  at Komponente.getName(script:10)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor316.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
  at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1850)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3758)
  at Komponente.getProperty(script)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:456)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:290)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:257)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedGetProperty$2.callStatic(Unknown Source)
  at Komponente.getName(script:10)
  ...

  (As you can see this repeates)
```

How can I access a class property in a Groovy script running on Jenkins, without getting `StackOverflowError` exception?

My system:

- Jenkins-version is 2.73.3
- JobDSL Plugin 1.68
- Stapler Groovy module `org.kohsuke.stapler:stapler-groovy:1.250`
- Apache Groovy `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.11`

I already did some searching for this error message, but all Jenkins-Issues I found were fixed and closed at least in 2.7.1 so should be included in my jenkins version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `getName()` method from your class. When you specify class field like `String name` you  get methods `String getName()` and `void setName(String name)` out of the box.

Keep in mind that Jenkins Groovy script execution environment is a little bit different than the plain Groovy (e.g. in Groovy console) - Jenkins uses [groovy-cps](https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps) execution environment.

In your case following class `org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker` caused errors - according to your stack trace calling `Komponente.getName()` triggered `Komponente.getProperty()` method through the following execution chain:

```
  at Komponente.getProperty(script)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:456)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:290)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:257)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedGetProperty$2.callStatic(Unknown Source)
  at Komponente.getName(script:10)
```

And `Komponente.getProperty()` triggered `Komponente.getName()` and you run into infinite loop that caused `StackOverflowError`.

Similar problem happened when I copied your class to my test pipeline script, here is the stack trace I got:

```
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.StackOverflowError: Excessively nested closures/functions at Komponente.getName(WorkflowScript:10) - look for unbounded recursion - call depth: 1025
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsFunction.invoke(CpsFunction.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsCallableInvocation.invoke(CpsCallableInvocation.java:40)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:62)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

It's not that straightforward as yours, but it is caused by the same thing. When I removed `String getName()` method it worked as expected. It should work for you as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow - I've read in the style guides that you don't need to create getters/setters but as I'm from java and this is my first time writing groovy it was easier for me - and as it worked in the web console I didn't thought about that could be a problem.